# How do you test a message expectation within a block in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test message expectation within a block in Rspec:

```
def a_method
  ALibrary.execute do |batch|
    batch.execute if a == 1 
  end
end
```

If I am stubbing out the `execute` method in `ALibrary`, how do I test that a message was sent to the inner `execute`?

```
allow(ALibrary).to receive(:execute).and_return(a_library_execute)
let(:a_library_execute) {double(execute:true)}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to be using `and_call_original` to ensure that your reciever will call the original.

See this: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method

ALibrary.should_receive(:execute).and_call_original

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `ALibrary.execute` to return your own test double you can the [`and_yield`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/yielding) response.

```
allow(ALibrary).to receive(:execute).and_yield(a_library_execute)
```